# Troubleshooting packetloss

Tags: packetloss, gameserver, hetzner

I currently own a couple of CS:GO gameservers which are hosted in Germany (hetzner). Recently (for the past weeks) some people have been getting weird lags (getting slightly teleported back, some of you may know it as rubberband lag). After doing some scans and checks we've identified it to be a network profile, specifically packetloss. The host has asked for tracert tests in both directions (from and to the dedi server), we've conducted some tests (to the dedi) which clearly show packetloss after a certain hop, however when i run tracert from the dedicated server it shows no signs of packetloss or anything weird. Basically, I've ran tracert tests on both directions but it only showed packetloss when i was running it from my network or any other. Why is this happening and what can i do to prove to the host that theres packetloss?

Pingplotter [tracert test](http://www.mediafire.com/download/r8851btkf85xqo2/pingplotter.rar) (10minutes, 310 samples) - rar download.
[tracert test](http://pastebin.com/vc794DWs) (pastebin) from a PC in germany.

Note: I'm currently leasing the server from a host so I cannot provide device model/configuration, except the information that i can access via ssh.

Comment: Nobody's going to download and open your RAR file (would you?). Just post screenshots of your test results in your question.

Comment: Understandable, i just uploaded a screenshot of it - http://imgur.com/NCzToWC

Comment: Seems like Hetzner is the source of [many problems](http://serverfault.com/search?tab=relevance&q=hetzner) here on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of comments:

1. Your PingPlotter results do in fact show a problem in the Hetzner network, beginning at the **core-backbone-100g-nbg.hetzner.de** hop and continuing through the remainder of the path. Without getting into the vagaries of analyzing a packet loss trace, suffice it to say that your trace does show a legitimate problem.
2. Run PingPlotter from multiple unassociated and unconnected networks in order to show that the problem isn't an anomaly from only a single network. The more independent trace results showing the problem that you can provide to Hetzner the more likely it is that they'll take you seriously and investigate the problem.